# Any way to enforce a property's type in a CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, casting, railo, cfc, lucee

I'm experiencing some weird typecasting issues here, not specific to Lucee (also in Railo). Could be that I'm just missing some crucial point here though...

I have a component:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfproperty name="thisId" type="String" default="-1" />
    <cfproperty name="thatId" type="String" default="-1" />
</cfcomponent>
```

Both properties are clearly typed as strings. I would expect that when I try to set an object or a number to one of these, the code would return an error.
But, seeing as I'm used to cfml doing the typecasting for me by now, I never thought twice about the fact that setting a number here is no problem at all. I was in fact under the assumption that all number I would try to set here would be cast to strings for me.

It seems this is not the case though.
After implementing some REST calls that contain derivatives of these components in the form of a serialized struct, I onticed that some where included as an integer and some were included as a string. When I noticed that, I dumped out the component itself and notice that setting a number where a string was expected as a property, the typing had been overwritten as a number.

The fact that Railo / Lucee still validates is in my opinion beyond useless. Either validate strict typing and throw an error / pass in a correctly typed variable, or validate loose typing and convert to the type the CFC is expecting if that is possible.
Railo / lucee implemented loose type validation here, but still decides to pass in the variable in its original type, not what the cfc expects per sé.

Seeing as I don't want to be typecasting every number to a string right now, is there a simple oversight here that could salvage my typing?

(I've already posted this in the Lucee mailing list, but without any results, just people confirming what I already said / disregarding the possibility that this is not expected behaviour.)

---

**update (as asked by Adam):**
What I see is the following (in my cfc component described above):

```
<!--- setting a string returns a string afterwards, as expected since the property is a type string initialy --->
<cfset componentName.setThisId('1') />
<cfset local.thisIsStillAString = componentName.getThisId() />

<!--- setting a number returns a number, which means we can no longer assume the property is a string, as it was initially set up --->
<cfset componentName.setThatId(12345) />
<cfset local.thisIsNoLongerAString = componentName.getThatId() />
```

In both cases I would expect that either:
- the input variable would get strictly evaluated as a string, which means that the second example would raise an error, seeing that it is actually a number
- the input variable would get loosely evaluated as a string, but would be cast to a string when passing the evaluation, which would mean that the second example would pass but would ultimately return a string, no longer a number.

In any case I would expect the property's original typing to be preserved, instead it gets changed to whatever type you're trying to set, as long as it passes the current loose evaluation.

Comment: As touched on "-1" is a string, so it's going to pass string validation. I don't doubt you are perceiving some issue, and I think you describe it in the para that starts "It seems this is not the case though." However whilst you describe some sort of issue, you're being a big vague. Can you actually *show us* what you are seeing as being incorrect behaviour, rather than simply telling us about it.

Comment: @AdamCameron: added a short explanation of what I'm talking about. Hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: Cheers. The type checking in CFML is precisely that: type *checking*. Not type "setting". So it checks whether some value can be used as a given type. It doesn't, however, *change* its type at all. Its a dynamically typed language, so it only changes the type of a value when the type *must* change for [some given functionality]. For example, if you have `a = "1"; b = a + a;`, internally it will cast "1" to 1. But it will not change `a` to contain a numeric rather than the original string. And it works the same in reverse (numbers to strings). This is just the way CFML works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the built-in accessor setters will do automatic type-validation, but will only do casting where necessary *and* possible.

Numeric/string/date/boolean values are all considered "simple", which is why the numeric data is passing the "string" type-validation.  Therefore, because it passed the validation, the casting is skipped.  On a personal note, I would prefer if it did more rigorous validation, but that's an issue for the bugtracker.

Now, if you *must* ensure that only actual string data can make its way into those properties, you can override the generated setter for the property to do more rigorous type-casting and/or validation (I've tested this only on Lucee):

```
/** Example.cfc */
component accessors=true {
    property type="string" name="thisId";
    property type="string" name="thatId";

    public function setThisId(required string newId) {
        // convert numeric value to string value
        if (isNumeric(newId)) {
            newId = toString(newId);

        // throw an exception for non-string/numeric values
        // !isSimpleValue() is a catch-all btw, structs and arrays will
        // be prevented by the "newId" argument's type hint
        } else if (isBoolean(newId) || isDate(newId) || !isSimpleValue(newId)) {
            throw(message="Invalid value specified for thisId");
        }

        variables.thisId = newId;
        return this;
    }
}

var example = new Example();

example.setThisId(54321);
example.setThatId(54321);
writeoutput(serializeJson(example)); //{"thisId":"54321","thatId":54321}

// throws exceptions:
example.setThisId(true);
example.setThisId({});
```

Finally, getting back to the "casting where necessary *and* possible" part.  For the given example, if you were to try passing a component instance to the `setThisId()` method, it fails the type-validation step, meaning type-casting is *necessary* for the operation to succeed.  So then the value is checked for the *possibility* of type-casting.  If the component (and this only works on Railo/Lucee) has a `_toString()` "magic method" defined, then type-casting is *possible*.  Since it is possible, the component is then cast to a string, and the result then passed into `setThisId()`.  If that magic method is not defined on the component, it is not possible to do type casting, and an exception is thrown.  Similarly for structs/arrays, type-casting is *necessary*, but not *possible* as there is no automatic serialization defined for those types, thus resulting in an exception being thrown.

### TL;DR

You can override the setter accessor to do more rigorous type-validation/type-casting.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce them as string (not array nor struct), use `accessor=true` together with your `<cfproperty>`'s and use setters.

However, if you're talking about `SerializeJSON()` treating strings of numbers as integers, that is not something `type="string"` can enforce.  It has to do with the behavior of the `SerializeJSON()` function.  If you really want to enforce them as string, try https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc

Comment: I'm already doing what you suggesting, but I' not talking about setting a struct in a string property. I'm talking about variable types that could get cast into a string according to Railo, like a number type, coming from a database query object for example.
When setting this variable in the string property of my CFC, Railo validates that number as a possible string but still sets the original variable in all its numerical glory in my CFC, diregarding the fact that it was a string property, not a number property.

I'm not talking about serializeJSON().

Comment: @dreagan anything other than query, array or struct/object are actually stored and manipulable as strings in CFML.  Therefore, numbers are also strings.

Comment: I could agree to that, but that does not mean a number data type IS actually a string data type, so why the lack of conversion / proper validation? If it is stored as a string, why not cast the number to an actual string data type? I'm all for loose typing, but what I said still goes, it makes absolutely no sense to perform validation on data types if you're not ging to enforce them.